# Handling cors error without support in Backend

Tags: reactjs, nginx, cors, vercel

I am running my frontend with `react` and `vercel serve`. I am sending a request to a backend server where CORS isn't handled. For frontend am running a container in a server with nginx. Was thinking of running a proxy server so that request is sent through server.
Is there any easier way to handle this instead of running a extra proxy server.

Answer (score 0):

if the server runs on your localhost you can use the browser CORS plugin (like Chrome Allow CORS Extension) to bypass the proxy but if it runs on the internet I don't think you have any other options.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).